# Does this trigonometric equation: $\frac {z}2 \csc \left(\frac{z}2\right)=1$, have solutions other than zero?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I wonder whether this equation has solutions other than zero?

$$\frac {z}2 \csc \left(\frac{z}2\right)=1$$

Wolfram alpha fails to solve.

Comment: Can $z$ be complex?

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi  yes

Comment: Absolutely, but do you need all the roots? Here's one example $z=14.9954 + 5.53736i$

Comment: @caverac do you have closed form for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call $z = x + i y$, then solving the equation

$$
z\;{\rm csc}z =1 
$$

Is equivalent to solve the pair of equations

$$
\sin x\cosh y = x \quad\mbox{and}\quad \cos x\sinh y = y
$$

This problem can be numerically solved using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Note that this system can be also written as

$$
\frac{\tan x}{x} = \frac{\tanh y}{y} = \alpha
$$

That allows you to see that there are solutions different from $z=0$, indeed if you fix $\alpha <0$, the problem is reduced to finding roots of $\tanh y = \alpha y$ and $\tan x = \alpha x$, which exist, but do not have a closed algebraic form.

Comment: But note that not every solution of $\tan x = \frac{\tanh y}{y}x$ is a solution of $\sin(x+iy)=x+iy$, e.g. it seems that generally  only the imaginary part of
$\frac{\sin(x+iy)}{x+iy}$ is near zero (tested with Maple and $y=2, 5,10,20).$ If there are solutions they should be computed with the 2-dimensional Newton.

Comment: @gammatester The imaginary part of $\sin z/z$ has to be zero, otherwise is not a solution

Comment: Yes I know. But your procedure: Fix $y$, then compute the root is not enough. Here the Maple log for $y=2:$

r := fsolve(tan(x)=x*tanh(2)/2, x=2..4.5);
r := 4.259111441; 
t := r+2*I; t/sin(t)-1;
t := 4.259111441+2.*I ;   -2.259243988+.4969856757e-9*I

Comment: @gammatester Sorry for the misunderstanding, I do realize that problem has to be simultaneously solved for both $x$ and $y$. My argument is that if somehow you manage to find $y$, then there is a solution for $x$ that cannot be written in a closed algebraic form. I will update my answer accordingly